# Animation Follow Path Constraint Distorted

Tags: animation, rigging

I am creating a car animation and i want it to go along a path using follow path. When I rig the empty to the path the car gets distorted.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

UPDATE: The distortion of the car was because the car was parented to an empty which was rigged onto the path. When i scaled the path along the x -axis, this caused the car also to distort. A simple scale using the Y-Axis helped me and works fine.

Comment: provide blend file....to check out

Comment: maybe check the radius of your curve vertices in Edit mode, in the N panel, if they are not set at 1, bring them back to 1. If it doesn't, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: And, apply scale on things.